# Symfony Shared Library Upgrade

Tags: symfony1

I have a symfony version 1.0.16 application that I want to upgrade to symfony 1.4. Symfony is currently installed as a shared library on my server. How can I convert from a server wide shared library to a domain specific symfony library?

Comment: "A shared library"? Do you mean Symfony is installed somewhere on your server and your pointing the lib/vendor folder of all your projects to it?

Answer (score 1):

I work every day on Symfony projects and one of the best practice i've adopted is:

Always embbed the symfony vendor libraries inside the applicacion (its the recommended by symfony when having non related projects hosted on same server).

So, steps to take in order to change from wide to local:

1. Create a vendor folder on `$sf_root/lib/`
2. Download and uncompress a symfony version inside `$sf_root/lib/vendor/symfony` folder
3. replace the symfony script on `$sf_root/` with the one on (`$sf_root/lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/symfony`)
4. Modify the `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` on config to start using the `lib/vendor/symfony` libraries. It should look something like this:

   ```
   require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
   sfCoreAutoload::register();

   class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration{
   .....}
   ```
5. Rebuild all classes
6. Verify your code. Plugins not always work with every symfony versions. Also if you created administrator modules (like the ones generated by propel), check if the `configuration.yml` it's still consistent.

Also this could be helpful (its a different version but could give ideas if something breaks) [Upgrade symfony project](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_4/en/upgrade)